# Adiabatic processes

Tags: thermodynamics, work, conventions, adiabatic

Adiabatic process is a process that involves no interactions other than work.

What I interpret from this is that change in energy = change in work done.

however it is not the case but it’s the NEGATIVE change in work done.

Why must it be negative change? Meaning work is done on the system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an adiabatic change,

Gain in internal energy = Work done on system = – work done by system

The confusion may arise because some writers use $w$ to mean work done on system, and others use $w$ to mean work done by system.

Thus you may see, for an adiabatic change, $\Delta U=w $ **or** $\Delta U=-w$.

However for a reversible change, the work done *by* the system is $p\ dV$, so for a reversible adiabatic change it is always the case that $dU=-p\ dV$.

[Work is energy in transit. "Change in work done" doesn't usually have any meaning, as work is not a property of the system, not something about the system that we can increase or decrease. In the language of thermodynamics, work is not a *function of state*. That's why many good writers refrain from using $\Delta w $ or $dw$, even for a small amount of work. Sometimes you see $dw$, with a cross-stroke through the stroke of the d, to signify that $dw$ doesn't represent the change in anything, just a small amount of work.]